# Show activity only once where ever the app is installed or re-installed

Tags: java, android

The below code works if you installed an app for the first it displays the register acctivity but if you uninstall and re-install the app, it doesn't take the user to register activity

```
Boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("isFirstRun", true);
        if (isFirstRun) {
            //show start activity
            startActivity(new Intent(Register.this, MainActivity.class));
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "First Run", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
        getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("isFirstRun", false).commit();
```

Please how do I modify this code t enable the register activity show on installing the application for every first time and thereafter never again.

Comment: first time per a device? or a user?

Comment: write a file on sd card that indecates that this device already registered.

Comment: Reinstalling is the same as installing. When app is deleted, all app info is deleted with it.

Comment: Shared Preference will also uninstalled with the application

Answer (score 1):

You can't rely on device's memory, because all data connected to the app (`SharedPreferences`) is deleted by Android when the user removes the app. Moreover, the device can be reset to factory settings and in this case any data saved in the device's memory will be erased as well.

The only 100% sure way to do what you want to do is to create an external database on the cloud where your app connects and send device's ID (MAC address) to get as result a flag indicating if it is the first run or not. The database in the cloud checks if it already contains the MAC address: if yes it means the app already executed on that device, otherwise it is the first time and the new MAC address is saved in the database

An easier (but not 100% sure) alternative is to generate a file in the device's memory for marking the device. If the app finds the file then it knows that has already been executed there. This method IMO is easier to implement and works pretty good except only in two cases: the user manually deletes the file or the device is reset to factory settings.

Comment: What mac address are you talking about exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Better way would be to create a db table which holds the information of first run.So on uninstall db would be deleted.

Comment: That's not better at all. For small bits of data, a database is overkill

Answer (score 0):

The if will execute true when the preferences are deleted, because you set true as the default in `getBoolean(...,true)`. Change every boolean to the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

there is two way to achieve this,

1. Cloud - store device id (or any other unique id for device) in cloud
2. Device - store a flag on device external storage

first way is more secure and reliable but u need internet connection and a server to store datas (could be cloud like azure or aws or your own server/api)

second way is much easier but its not reliable due the fact that external storage could be erased or detached .

so best solution so far is store device id in cloud and check it during install or application start process.